# Simple CDF question

Tags: probability

What are the steps needed to turn the LHS of the following equation into the second and third steps in the following equation:

Let Z be a RV with standard normal distribution. Then
$Pr(|Z|\le x)\ge .95$ $ =  1 - \Phi (x)$ = $Pr(Z>x)\le 0.025$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The explicit steps:
$$
Pr(|Z|\leq x)=Pr(-x\leq Z\leq x)=Pr(-x<Z\leq x).
$$
The second equality above uses the continuity of $Z$. Proceed:
$$
Pr(-x<Z\leq x)=\Phi(x)-\Phi(-x)=\Phi(x)-(1-\Phi(x))=2\Phi(x)-1.
$$
So
$$
0.95\leq Pr(-x<Z\leq x)\implies 0.95\leq2\Phi(x)-1\implies\Phi(x)\geq 0.975.
$$
Subtract both sides in the last inequality from $1$ gives $Pr(z>x)\leq 0.025$.

Comment: Thanks Kim, if only you ran your country with such clarity. Would you have any idea as to why my textbook decided to derive 1−Φ(x) instead of just solving for x by inverting 1−Φ(x)≥0.975. The book explains it as "For each positive number x, it will be true that Pr(|Z|<=x) >= 0.95 iff 1 - Φ(x) = Pr(Z > x) <= 0.025."

Comment: @ OP: You're welcome. My guess would be that saying $Pr(Z>x)\leq 0.025$ makes it more intuitive for students when they go look up $x$ in a table printed somewhere in the book.